# Where/How to setup paths in CMake cross-build project

Tags: c++, path, cmake, cross-platform

I have a C++ project which generates a main-binary and a couple of supporting binaries and libraries (DLLs/SOs). Also there is a bit of additional data (assets, text files...)

There is currently a crude way in use using a mix of CMake and Shell scripts to install all these which is quite bad especially for package systems.
What we (OpenSource project) want is

1. Basic install into /usr/local (bin, share,...)
2. Install into one directory (especially for windows or nightlies)

The problem: How does the program know where/how it was installed? Currently the paths are set in CMake (*_BINDIR, *_DATA, *_GAMEDIR) and passed as defines to the program. For the case 2. a base path of "." is used (required e.g. for distributed versions of the compiled program), for case 1. the paths are absolute.

But how do other projects solve this? Do they simply use relative paths (to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX) and set CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to "." or "/"? What about DESTDIR?

So basically: How to set the paths correctly and let the compiled program know about them without breaking the ability to distribute the compiled program?

Comment: DESTDIR is unrelated to your problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710782/cmake-resources-locations-and-destdir. `How does the program know where/how it was installed?` - `CMakeLists.txt` may conclude target type from [variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-variables.7.html#id4). Then you may use [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html) for generate header file.

Comment: The linked question helps indeed for DESTDIR. The other stuff is already done like that. The question is: How to specify the paths and how do others do that (or is there a *right* way)? Would it be acceptable to just have CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, make everything relative to that and store the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in a (configured) define?